# Maven error: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec

Tags: java, maven, netbeans

I'm using netbeans. I tried to reinstall it but it did not work.
Following is the stack trace when I run mvn clean install -X:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
        at org.neuroph.util.NeurophArrayList.get(NeurophArrayList.java:376)
        at org.neuroph.core.Layer.getNeuronAt(Layer.java:230)
        at org.neuroph.util.ConnectionFactory.forwardConnect(ConnectionFactory.java:231)
        at neuralNetwork.util.NeuralNetworkBuilder.customStandardNNet(NeuralNetworkBuilder.java:34)
        at com.mycompany.redneuronal.redNeuronal.main(redNeuronal.java:25)
------------------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD FAILURE
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time: 1.157s
Finished at: Sun Mar 04 17:00:22 ART 2018
Final Memory: 5M/123M
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec (default-cli) on project perceptron: Command execution failed. Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec (default-cli) on project perceptron: Command execution failed.
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:217)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Command execution failed.
        at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.execute(ExecMojo.java:362)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
        ... 19 more
Caused by: org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1)
        at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.executeInternal(DefaultExecutor.java:377)
        at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute(DefaultExecutor.java:160)
        at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.executeCommandLine(ExecMojo.java:610)
        at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.execute(ExecMojo.java:352)
        ... 21 more
```

Also I tried to reinstall maiven and delete my local repository. 
I'd be grateful if you could help me.

Comment: Which version of Maven are you running? Have you tried to upgrade the exec-maven-plugin version?

Answer (score 7):

Solved by upgrading exec-maven-plugin 1.2.1 to 1.6.0 on my NetBeans project.

You can do this the following way:

```
Project > Properties > Actions
```

Once there, select run proyect and replace "org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec" with "org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.6.0:exec".

[Check the following](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ACKUF.png)